# Media Player getting stopped. I need to run it even if the app killed

Tags: android, service, background, android-mediaplayer

Using Service for achieving the Question purpose.

code :

inside manifest :

```
<service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

service class :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer media;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    media = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    media.setLooping(true);
    media.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    media.stop();
}
```

My Java class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startMethod(View v) {
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void stopMethod(View v) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

So, the issue is that, When I am killing the app, media player stops the playing music or my default ringtone. since, i am using START_STICKY, it should run in background.

What might be the issue ? I need to play the music even if app killed using service in android. Please, guide if there something wrong. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The above issue is working fine for lower version devices. For higher version we can use JobService.

Now, the Question is What if I want to check the specific time in background service, and at particular time I have to display a toast message. So far, I have done it inside onStartCommand() method and comparing time with .equals method. But, I think there's another way to do so..

my code inside onStartCommand():

```
if(currentTime.equals("Thu Mar 29 06:18:00 GMT 2018")){
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(currentTime.equals("Thu Mar 29 06:20:00 GMT 2018")){
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(currentTime.equals("Thu Mar 29 06:21:00 GMT 2018")){
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Toast not displaying at these particular times. because it display only when the onStartCommand() method calls. So, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: are u using android 8.0 (Oreo)?

Comment: no, am using android 6.0 marshmallow and 7.0 nagut.

Comment: which thing is necessary if we are using 8.0 ?

Comment: In higher version android devices the system may kill the service as soon as the phone enters doze state. Use JobService for higher version devices.

Comment: are u sure ur not calling stopService() in ondestroy() ?

Comment: no, i have already posted code. just media.stop() inside ondestroy().

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal It's working in Genymotion 4.1.1 device. Thanks. But, What for getting working in >=6.0 devices ?

Comment: m not sure, but you can try and use a JobService, and let me know if it works.

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal thanks and will you please check my edit in question.

Answer (score 1):

If this is working in lower version android devices, then you can try and use a JobService for higher android version devices.

Follow the links below & become a pro at JobScheduling:

https://github.com/evernote/android-job

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/scheduling-work-jobscheduler

https://blog.klinkerapps.com/android-o-background-services/

Comment: Thank you so much dude... (sir). ;)

Comment: use onStartJob() if ur starting a JobService, otherwise keep using onStartCommand() for lower versions.

Comment: So, my way is correct of checking if conditions inside onStartCommand() method ?

Comment: I have to check the time in background service and it gets eual with particular time, then toast should be display. how ? not using JobService.

Comment: just store the startTime and compute the difference from the current time when needed

Comment: but, how can i check or fire a event when my time gets equal in background ? i can compare the time. no issue but, when ? When in background ? Or how can I check continuously for specific time in background ?

Comment: Should I need to use The AlarmManager for that ?

Comment: yes, u can use alarm manager or even a post delayed handler to run a task after a particular time interval.